# I can't figure out an issue with Laravel image storage and display

Tags: php, laravel, image

I've been working with Laravel for a few months now and i think i have a decent grasp of it.
Recently, i was working on building a portfolio website for myself, and wanted it to fetch data from my database and display a bunch of them in a "project" page. It was working mostly fine until i changed computers ( from a desktop to a work dedicated laptop )
I transferred over my app files so that i could keep working with it as soon as the laptop was setup, and it seemed to work fine, but i'm now facing an issue i cannot debug for the life of me.

While my page displaying projects correctly fetches data from the database, the image for each project is not displaying. Instead i get the little icon for when an image is broken ( the white and green one)

When i say i cant debug it for the life of me, here are the steps i followed :

The initial image storage is from a function that register it in the Database

```
public function storeProject(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->all());
        // Valider les données du formulaire
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'image_1' => 'required|file|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png|max:4000',
            'description' => 'required|string',
            'url' => 'required|url',
            'customer' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'mission' => 'required|string|max:191',
            'tags' => 'nullable|array',
        ]);
        //dd($validatedData);

        // convert string to array
        $mission = $validatedData['mission'] ? [$validatedData['mission']] : [];


        //Enregistrer les image sur notre serveur


        $imagePaths = [];
        $images = [$request->file('image_1'), $request->file('image_2'), $request->file('image_3')];
        foreach ($images as $image) {
            if ($image) {
                $filename = time() . '-' . $image->getClientOriginalName();
                $path = $image->storeAs('public/images/' . $filename);
                $imagePaths[] = $filename;
            }
        }


        // Nouveau projet avec les données validées du formulaire
        $project = new projet;
        $project->name = $validatedData['name'];
        $project->image_1 = $imagePaths[0] ?? null;
        $project->description = $validatedData['description'];
        $project->url = $validatedData['url'];
        $project->customer = $validatedData['customer'];
        $project->mission = $validatedData['mission'];
        $project->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $project->save();

        // tags
        $tags = $validatedData['tags'];
        $project->addtags($tags);
        // categories

        $project->addCategory($mission);
        return redirect()->route('moderate')->with('success', 'Projet mis en Ligne avec succès.');

        // redirection avec errors
    }
```

This function works, the database registers the data correctly, and it is displayed correctly ( minus the image ) when fetched by the blade view.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Portfolio')

@section('content')

    <div class="containers">
        <div class="mobilemenubar">

        </div>
        <div class="column">

            <div class="BackgroundImage">
                <img src="{{ Storage::url('/images/Homeimage.jpg') }}" alt="Background-Image" />

                <div class="project-container">
                    {{--                 We use the Modulo operator here : passing projects to the view in an array, we check the array's index with the modulo operator to see if the index is dividable by 2, if so we give it a value of 0 if not a value of 1, then use an odd/even system to alternate layouts --}}
                    <div class="addbutton">
                        <a href="{{ route('add-project') }}">Ajouter un nouveau Projet</a>
                    </div>
                    @foreach ($projects as $index => $project)
                        @if ($index % 2 === 0)
                            <div class="project-first-layout">
                                <div class="first-layout-image-box"> <img
                                        src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . $project->image_1) }}" alt="{{ $project->name }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="first-layout-text-area"> {{ $project->description }} </div>
                                <div class="externals">
                                    <a href="{{ $project->url }}" class="external-link">Visiter le Site</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="external-link">Git</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <form action="  {{ route('edit-project', $project->id) }}" method="GET">
                                        @csrf

                                        <button type="submit">Modifier</button>
                                    </form>
                                    <form action=" {{ route('delete-project', $project->id) }}"class="Delete"
                                        method="POST">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        <button type="submit">Supprimer</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @else
                            <div class="project-second-layout">
                                <div class="second-layout-image-box"><img
                                        src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . $project->image_1) }}" alt="{{ $project->name }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="second-layout-text-area">{{ $project->description }}</div>
                                <div class="externals">
                                    <a href="{{ $project->url }}" class="external-link">Visiter le Site</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="external-link">Git</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="buttons">
                                    <form action=" {{ route('edit-project', $project->id) }}" method="GET">
                                        @csrf

                                        <button type="submit">Modifier</button>
                                    </form>
                                    <form action=" {{ route('delete-project', $project->id) }}"class="Delete"
                                        method="POST">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('DELETE')
                                        <button type="submit">Supprimer</button>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                </div>
                <div class="Navbuttons">
                    <div class="AdminWelcomeBox">
                        <h1>Mes Projets</h1>
                    </div>
                    @include('components.admin-navmenu')
                    <div id="adminsocials">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook fa-4x" id="Facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter fa-4x" id="Twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa-brands fa-linkedin fa-4x" id="Linkedin"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>




            </div>
        </div>





    @endsection
```

In this case the error comes from first-layout-image-box and second-layout-image-box that dont return the images properly ( while HomeImage is displayed properly)

-I've tried : using Storage::url helper, using asset() helper, using just url() helper, and none of these worked.
-I made sure my php artisan storage:link is set up, and it is
-I've cleared caches

This is my filesystems setup :

```
'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
            'throw' => false,
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
            'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
            'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
            'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
            'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
            'throw' => false,
        ],

    ],
```

It is worth noting i'm (cucrently) hosting it locally through WAMP and it didnt seem to have any issue beforehand before i switched PC

Comment: so you did move the images that was on your local storage to the hosted storage ?

Comment: The images (through my testing i deleted previous one as i delete my preojects used for tests) are stored automatically in the storage\app\public\images folder as i save them through a form to save them in database. From my understanding, the storage link symlink should default there, thus i dont understand why they dont display ...

Comment: The storage link symlink won't link it as default until you runing `php artisan storage:link`, it's because you might change the link path as you want in **config/filesystem.php**.

Comment: running php artisan storage:link tells me the link is already present, hence why i said the symlink should default there. And you can see the filesystem in the post. I even tried making a test page that pointed to a local_path with one of the images, and that one worked, but likely because its directly calling the iage by name, and not dynamically like i'm trying to

Comment: Well, unfortunately windows does not support symlink, there's the problem. Since I can't help you on apache, suggest searching some like "Laravel symlink on windows" probably help.

Comment: You might try to remove the link you created on public then running `php artisan storage:link` create new link.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the storage folder in public
And then use

> `Php artisan storage:link`

Again